# R - Character set is not UTF-8; please change your locale

Tags: r, debian

After a long struggle I've configured R Server and rApache on Debian Wheezy. I'm able to install packages and do stuff. But when i write some functions I get the error as mentioned in the subject line.

When I write this command - `Sys.getlocale()`. I get the reply as `"C"`.

Tried searching the forums but i couldn't get it. Some please help me to get a solution for it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does `Sys.getlocale()` really only return `"C"`? Mine says a whole bunch of stuff. Could you add the output from `sessionInfo()$locale` to the question? (It is in fact calling `Sys.getlocale()` internally, but formats the output in a nicer way.)

Comment: @Backlin There is a `"C"` locale that doesn't have separate `LC_` components. Oh,  and `sessionInfo()$locale` returns the same thing as `Sys.getlocale()`; the pretty formatting is due to `print.sessionInfo` that only happens on the whole results of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: I've had a wild guess, but you may get better answers if you provide the function that you tried to call, and the output from `traceback()`.

Comment: @Unknown User - did any of the solutions work? If so, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you with RStudio, and I think it has to do with the language settings/character encodings we chose during the install of our systems. Fortunately, I found an answer that worked for me here:

[**How to set up a clean UTF-8 environment in Linux**](http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment)

The above worked for me. Give it a try.

Comment: Did it work? When configuring `locales`, I selected `en_US.UTF-8`, so running `sessionInfo()` in R gets me `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` (everything else `...=C`). Rstudio hasn't complained once since the update.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `options(encoding = "UTF-8")`.